# Google reCAPTCHA not working IE11

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I am having an issue with Google reCAPTCHA not working properly in IE 11. 
Checkbox widget not working when I select the correct images. It refreshes the recaptcha and doesn't validate/go nowhere. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq.

[image]

I have tried the steps Google suggest except for the first one (update browser) as I would like it to work for on IE11 as its a popular browser version for our users.

Is there any alternatives/suggestion for form submission security?
Thx

Comment: I believe I found out the problem. I have tested the page with IE edge in compatibility mode IE7 and showed exactly the screenshot above. IE11 doesn't have developer tools so I am guessing the IE11 page was rendering IE7 compat mode.